# Trouble while using thaw on the serialized data structure in perl

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures, storable

I am using perl DB_File module to persist the hash variable into a file.

My hash variable contains key as normal string and value as another hash variable.

I used `Storable::freeze(\%value);` to serialize the hash value.

But when I tried to retrieve the values, I got an error. For the first time when I run the retrieve code, it works. The next consecutive times, it fails.

I used method like this:

```
tie(%HASH, "DB_File", "dbfile", O_RDWR, 0444); 
foreach $key (%HASH)
{
    $hashRef = Storable::thaw($HASH{$key};  --> here it fails with the error 
}
```

### Error message

> Storable binary image v25.47 more recent than I am (v2.7) at
>   ../../lib/Storable.pm (autosplit into ../../lib/auto/Storable/thaw.al)
>   line 366, at retrieve.pl line 15 at ../../lib/Storable.pm (autosplit
>   into ../../lib/auto/Storable/logcroak.al) line 74
>   Storable::logcroak('') called at ../../lib/Storable.pm (autosplit into
>   ../../lib/auto/Storable/thaw.al) line 367 Storable::thaw('2/8') called
>   at retrieve.pl line 15

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the error:

```
.... Storable::thaw('2/8') called ....
```

The value that you are trying to thaw is the scalar result of a hash.

I assume that the `$HASH{$key}` in

```
$hashRef = Storable::thaw($HASH{$key});
```

contains a hash (may be of frozen objects).

Try to add

```
use Data::Dumper;
print 'content : '.Dumper $HASH{$key};
```

before you try to thaw the value, to see its content.

Answer (score 0):

```
Storable::thaw($HASH{$key};
```

You forget to close  ()

```
Storable::thaw($HASH{$key});
```

And are you shure you need thaw all keys?
I think you have few fields and not all of them have to be Storable.